# Error Gráfico en el jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Es un error que es una tontería pero no se como solucionarlo. Resulta que con jquery y ajax logro desplegar una lista con una serie de viajes que tengo que mostrar, pero aparecen los viajes precedidos por una línea con un "." que lo hace poco atractivo y no se a que es debido ¿Sabéis si me falta alguna librería que cargar o me sobra alguna?

Os pego el trozo de código dónde está situado el textbox

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="evento_nuevo.aspx.vb" Inherits="CruceroSingle.evento_nuevo" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" runat="server" />
            <div>
                <asp:TabContainer ID="Tableta" runat="server">
                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Pestañas" ID="Pestas">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            hola
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                </asp:TabContainer>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Gracias

[image: Captura de Pantalla del Error]

Comment: Seguramente estas ocupando la etiqueta de listas ```<li>```. Si es así, con css debes poner list-style: none

Comment: Tu código no muestra cuando aparece la lista de resultados, que es donde está el problema

Comment: No entiendo el error que me estás indicando, lo siento.

Comment: Yussef se refiere a que el código mostrado es el que está **sin** renderizar en el navegador. Click derecho, inspeccionar elemento, copia el código generado y agrégalo a la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Acabo de completar el texto con todo el código fuente. Esto es todo lo que tengo

Comment: El código fuente es una cosa, el código que genera ese código fuente es otra cosa, en el navegador, en esa zona que dice `Crucero por Grecia en Malta...`, click derecho, inspeccionar elemento y el código que ves a ese nivel es el código que tu código fuente ha generado, a ese código es al que se refiere Yussef.

Comment: No es un *error gráfico en el jQuery*, es una cuestión de estilos CSS. Seguramente lo que estás generando es una lista `<ul>` donde cada opción en un elemento `<li>`. Ese punto junto a cada opción es representación de cada elemento `<li>`, tienes que darle o forzarle estilo a los `<li>` de esa lista concreta `<ul>` para que no tengan el punto, esto se hace con CSS `list-style: none`